# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on starting application

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I have strange thing here. I have UITableViewController with all required methods from protocols, and data that I will use in it. Then I have this code (simplified)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSDictionary* cellData = [self.tableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// the rest of the code

return cell;
}
```

This TableViewController should be executed after few clicks, so it is not called or referenced in AppDelegate or anywhere in ViewController that is loaded at the beginning.
But, when I build (successfully) and run application in simulator, it exits with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error before anything is displayed. I figured out that when I comment line:

```
NSDictionary* cellData = [self.tableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Everything is working normally. How come this have anything with this?
Also, tableViewData is loaded in viewDidLoad and it is not released prior this line, and everything else is ok (I can even delete lines below this). It shouldn't even send this error anyway, but it does and it is done on application startup. What gives?

EDIT: 
Here is viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tableViewData = [self getABContactsWithMail]; //gets filtered contacts from addressbook, works fine
}
```

Here are other parts of code :

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
self.tableViewData = nil;
}

-(void)dealloc{
[tableViewData release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

EDIT:
This is what I get from po tableViewData in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
<__NSArrayM 0xfdcfe30>(
{
email = "test@test.com";
firstName = test;
fullName = "test account";
id = 1;
lastName = account;
phone = "1 (231) 23";
},
{
email = "gmail@email.com";
firstName = nolast;
fullName = nolast;
id = 3;
lastName = "";
phone = "";
},
{
email = "asdkjf@sdfklja.com";
firstName = "";
fullName = nofirst;
id = 4;
lastName = nofirst;
phone = "";
},
{
email = "test@adsfk.com";
firstName = "";
fullName = "aaa.test@adsfk.com";
id = 5;
lastName = "";
phone = "";
}
)
```

EDIT: 
I added method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and I get same behavior with dummy data. It seems that something is wrong with UITableViewController itself or my xcode is messed up...

Comment: What is tableViewData? Is that an array that you created? If so, how and where are instantiating it?

Comment: Can you show the property declaration, the init code and cleanup code around tableViewData?

Comment: What is `tableViewData`? Provide the code in `viewDidLoad`. Thanks.

Comment: tableViewData is NSArray of NSDictionary. When I put breakpoint on that line, everything is there. It is retained in viewDidLoad and it is always there (loaded from address book)

Comment: you need to provide some other info. it's difficult to understand what is going on.

Comment: what type of policy do you use for tableViewData property? copy, retain or assign?

Comment: Include a stack trace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it by trial and error. Apparently my UITableViewController implements some of the protocols which were already implemented in it's parent class. And that was the whole problem...

I really don't know why entire application crushed on irrelevant place with irrelevant error. If this was my coding mistake then compiler should warn me at least.

Also I remember that I was doing this without problem on Xcode 3 ...

I submitted this as bug to Apple...

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us your method
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Should look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableViewData count];
}
```

Comment: It is like you stated. Also number of sections is 1 as it should be